# Proof that $\;\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\;$ is a bounded function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't quite understand how $\dfrac1 x$ is unbounded while $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ is not.

Comment: $\frac 1x$ is unbounded because the denominator can be close to zero, while $1+x^2\ge 1$.

Comment: The denominator is at least as large as $\max\{1,x^2\}$.  This makes $x/(1+x^2)$ bounded by $\min\{|x|,1/|x|\}$, which makes it bounded for both small $x$ and large $x$.  On the other hand $1/x$ is not bounded for small $x$.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^\pm}\dfrac1x=\pm\infty\;$ but $\;\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac x{x^2+1}=0\;,\;$ hence the function $f(x)=\dfrac1x$ is unbounded in any neighbourhood of $0$ but the function $g(x)=\dfrac x{x^2+1}$ is not.

Comment: How about $\frac{1}{x}$ is unbounded while $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} +x}$ is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at where $\dfrac 1 x$ goes to infinity,  what causes that unbounded behavior?  Notice that that is avoided in the second function.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is an alternative approach for the sake of curiosity.

\begin{align*}
|x^{2} + 1| = x^{2} + 1 \geq 2\sqrt{x^{2}} = 2|x| \Longleftrightarrow \left|\frac{x}{x^{2}+1}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2} \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{x}{x^{2}+1}\leq\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding $x/(1+x^2)$, it may help to analyze the cases $|x| \leq 1$ and $|x| > 1$ separately.

In the former case you have a continuous function everywhere defined on a closed interval (here it's important that there's squaring in the denominator; nothing is getting close to zero down there), so it's going to be bounded. You can also do algebra with the hypothesis $|x| \leq 1$ and derive an explicit bound, or be more sophisticated and verify that a particular number is the least upper bound for the function on that interval.

For $|x| > 1$ one can leverage the fact that in this instance $|x| < |x|^2$ and hence $|x/(1 + x^2)| = |x|/(1 + |x|^2) \leq |x|^2/(1 + |x|^2)$ and this last fraction is less than $1$ because it has the form $a/b$ with $a$ and $b$ positive numbers and $a < b$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\quad\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\space (x)=0
\qquad \text{while}\qquad 
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\space (x^n+1)=1\quad$$
so the limit is as follows

$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty\qquad
\text{while}\qquad 
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\bigg(\frac{x}{x^2+1}\bigg)
=\left(\frac{\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\space (x)}
       {\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\space (x^n+1)}\right)
=\frac{0}{1}=0$$